# How to say "attendance/absence" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

*Attendance* and *absence* in the sense of attending or skipping a lecture.

*e.g.* in the sentence:

> If you continue to skip your lectures, your attendance will be poor and eventually fail those modules.

Dankon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For attendance I would say *ĉeesto* and for absence *foresto*. Maybe for skipping lectures you can say *preterlasi*. So a complete translation of your example could be:

> Se vi daŭre preterlasos viajn lekciojn, via ĉeestado estos malalta kaj finfine vi malsukcesos je tiuj kursoj.

Comment: Vi estas la plej bona(･`ω･) Dankon!

Comment: What indication is there that *ĉeesto* and *preterlasi* are actually used this way?

Answer (score 2):

"Attendance" in the sense of a record of the number of times that you've participated in something is ***vizitado***.

El PIV:

- doni al studento ateston pri vizitado.

El Vivo Vokas:

- Iu fariĝas plej eminenta en kurado, alia en naĝado, tria en ŝakludo, kvara en preĝejvizitado

So, it seems that *vizitado* is something that is measured, that people can excel at, and which I school might provide a record for - like "attendance".

Comment: As for "to skip", perhaps this FB discussion will be of interest. Suggestions include: Forlasi, transsalti, preterlasi, maltrafi, ellasi, salti,   https://www.facebook.com/groups/konsultejo/permalink/2027076150650730/